# HQL how to join two tables with out any association

Tags: sql, join, hql

I have searched around and some answers are using criteriabuilder, my prob is in HQL.
I have two tables A & B, they are not associated in anyway but I need to match one from each field to get the value of fieldB2 from the table B.

My query:

```
Table A - fieldA1 (ex. value of '20'), fieldA2 A
Table B - fieldB1 (ex. value of '20'), fieldB2 B
```

this doesn't work:

```
select new map (fieldA1 as fa, (select fieldB1 from B as b where a.fieldA1=b.fieldB1) as fb) from A as a
```

so basically, I need to get fieldB1 from B if the value it consists is the same with the value of fieldA1 from A.

what is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to write HQL or query using Criteria without association.

Use native SQL query to retrieve the records.

Comment: I figured that might be the case, but is there a work around not using native sql? thanks

Comment: No. There are no workarounds. Simple, if you write HQL, hibernate will translate that to SQL. But how will hibernate know how two classes are related if there are no associations (relationship)?